# kendo ui grid filtering, pager not updated

Tags: kendo-ui

i have encountered a problem on filtering in kendo 2012.3.1315.340  grid filtering,     i    have textboxes on the header template for filter function, once i  filter, my paging is not working properly, i get proper data but my page count      and total records don't change on the UI

Here is my code..

```
function searchOnFilters(element) {
    var filtersModel = getSearchFilters();

    //debugger;
    var filterResults = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 50,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("MasterQA_Read", "MasterQA")',


                data: { searchFilters: JSON.stringify(filtersModel) },
                type: "POST"

            }
        },

        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
            return kendo.stringify(data);
        },
        schema: {

            data: "Data",
            total : "Total"
                 }

    });

    filterResults.fetch(function () {
       // debugger;
        var grid = $("#MQASearchGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource = filterResults;
        grid.refresh();
    });


}
```

Controller:

```
         var result1 = new DataSourceResult
         {
             Data = gridData.Items,
             Total = gridData.TotalCount
         };
         return Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Why do you assign a new DataSource instead of fetching data with previous datasource?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [setDataSource](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-setDataSource) method of the grid. Assigning the [dataSource](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#fields-dataSource) field has no effect.